# Creating AST using JJTree

Tags: java, javacc

I am trying to build a parser using JavaCC and have it build me an AST using JJTree from JavaCC. I get mixed results, but neither of them are an AST. I have tried to add # followed by a name to each non terminal's function so a node would be created, but then I get errors 30+ errors regarding visitor pattern.
My goal is just to get a simple AST outputted, but everytime I try to adjust it, I just get an error. Any help is much appreciated.

```
options {
    MULTI = true;
}
PARSER_BEGIN(JJTree)

public class JJTree {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          System.out.println("Reading from standard input...");
          JJTree t = new JJTree(System.in);
          try {
            SimpleNode n = t.Start();
            n.dump("");
            System.out.println("Thank you.");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Oops.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
}
PARSER_END(JJTree)

//Tokens
SKIP : {
" " | "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n"
}

/*
Math operators
 */
TOKEN : {
  < PLUS : "+" >
| < MUL : "*">
| < DIV : "/">
| < MINUS : "-">
| < ASSIGN : "=">
| < SMALLER : "<">
| < BIGGER : ">">
| < EQUALS : "==">
| < AND : "&&">
| < OR : "||">
}

/*
Reserved words
 */
TOKEN : {
  < NUMBER : ("number")>
| < TEXT : ("text")>
| < BOOLEAN : ("boolean")>
| < TRUE : ("true")>
| < FALSE : ("false")>
| < SHOW : ("show")>
| < REPEAT : ("repeat")>
| < IS : ("is")>
| < WHILE : ("while")>
| < CREATE : ("create") >
| < TASK : ("task")>
| < TIMES : "times">
| < THEN : "then">
| < NOTHING : "nothing">
| < ELSE : "else">
}

/*
Seperators
 */
TOKEN : {
  <LPAREN: "(">
| <RPAREN: ")">
| <LBRACE: "{">
| <RBRACE: "}">
| <LBRACKET: "[">
| <RBRACKET: "]">
| <SEMICOLON: ";">
| <COMMA: ",">
| <DOT: ".">
| <QUOTES: "\"">
}

TOKEN : {
  < NUMBER_VALUE : (< DIGIT >)+>
| < #DIGIT : ["0" - "9"]>
| < #LETTER : ["_","a"-"z","A"-"Z"]>
| < IDENTIFIER : <LETTER> (<LETTER>|<DIGIT>)*>
| < TEXT_LITERAL: "\""
                        (   (~["\"","\\","\n","\r"])
                          | ("\\"
                              ( ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","'","\""]
                              | ["0"-"7"] ( ["0"-"7"] )?
                              | ["0"-"3"] ["0"-"7"] ["0"-"7"]
                              )
                            )
                        )*
                        "\"">
}

SimpleNode Start() #START : {}
{
(
  LOOKAHEAD(2)
  Assignment()
| Print()
| ControlStruct()
| Task()
)
{return jjtThis;}
}

void Assignment() #ASSIGN :{}
{
    (<BOOLEAN> | <NUMBER> | <TEXT> )? ID() <ASSIGN> (BoolExp() | LOOKAHEAD(2) Arithmetic() | <NUMBER_VALUE> | ID() | <TEXT_LITERAL>)
}

void Arithmetic() #ARITHMETIC :{}
{
    ((ID() | <NUMBER_VALUE> ) (<PLUS> | <MINUS> | <DIV> | <MUL> ) (ID() | <NUMBER_VALUE> ))+
}

void Print() :{}
{
    <SHOW> <LPAREN> ID() <RPAREN>
}

void ControlStruct() :{}
{
    Repeat()
    | Is()
    | While()
}

void Repeat() :{}
{
    <REPEAT> ID() <NUMBER_VALUE> <TIMES>
}

void Is() :{}
{
    <IS> Expression() <THEN> Statement() Is1()
}

void Is1() :{}
{
    (<ELSE> Expression())?
}

void While() :{}
{
    <WHILE> <LPAREN> Expression() <RPAREN> Statement()
}

void Task() :{}
{
    ReturnType() <TASK> ID() <LPAREN> Input() <RPAREN>
}

void ReturnType() :{}
{
    <NUMBER>
    | <TEXT>
    | <NOTHING>
}

void Input() :{}
{
    ((<NUMBER> | <TEXT> ) ID())?
}

void BoolExp() :{}
{
    <TRUE>
    | <FALSE>
}

void Expression() :{}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(2)
    <NUMBER_VALUE> (<BIGGER> | <SMALLER> | <EQUALS>) <NUMBER_VALUE>
    | <TEXT_LITERAL> <EQUALS> <TEXT_LITERAL>
}

void Statement() :{}
{
    Assignment()
}

void ID() :{}
{
  <IDENTIFIER>
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  I'd suggest. (a) Delete all generated files.  (b) Run JJTree. (c) Run JavaCC.  (d) Run JavaC.

Comment: If that doesn't work, edit your question to say exactly what you are doing and exactly what error message(s) you get at each stage.